# How to reopen the Join the Stormcloaks quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Earlier in the game I couldn't continue the main quest because of the Join the Stormcloaks bug ([more information](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Ulfric_Stormcloak_Bug_-_Joing_The_Stormcloaks_&_Season_Unending)): I had to use the *setstage xyz* command to fail the Joining the Stormcloaks quest to proceed.

But now I can't take it on. I talked to the guy in Windhelm who sent me to kill an Ice Wraith, but after ending the conversation with him, the quest disappeared from my journal and I can't see it anywhere: I tried using the *setstage* command again to make progress (`setstage CW01B 100` should make the quest go to *return to Galmar* stage, but nothing happens.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the footnotes on [Joining the Stormcloaks (UESP)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Joining_the_Stormcloaks) reads:

> On the PC, it is possible to use the console to advance through the quest by entering *setstage CW01B stage*, where *stage* is the number of the stage you wish to complete. **It is not possible to un-complete (i.e. go back) quest stages.**

(Emphasis mine.) Looks like you're not a true brother or sister of Skyrim.

However, if you have a save from before using the console (always a good precaution, but not one we always remember), you could try going back and instead of advancing the Stormcloaks questline, advance the main one. You may miss a bit of content, but at least you'll be able to do both.

To skip past talking to Ulfric, use `setstage mq302 30`. Alternatively, just complete "Joining the Stormcloaks" (and possibly also "The Jagged Crown") so that Ulfric will stop acting like your mission commander and start acting like a leader at a meeting.

> Source: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending#Bugs

Comment: I'll be damned. F*ck... Well, I hope I will at least be able to go with Imperials and save Stormcloaks for next play :(

Comment: I have the same problem but when i type in the console command it saus missing parameter stage ?

Comment: You could try `resetquest mq302`